# Splitting a node-style callback into two callbacks

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, callback, ecmascript-6

I am putting together an example that shows how a simple synchronous Node.js program can be transformed into an asynchronous version that uses async/await. There should be several intermediate steps, starting with a normal callback-based version, following up with one that uses two callbacks, one for the normal (resolve) case and another for the error (reject) case, which would then lead to promises.

The job of each version is to create an empty folder *copy* (which might exist already and it might contain files) and copy all files (called *file1.txt* and *file2.txt*) in the folder *orig* there. If an error occurs anywhere it should be explicitly caught, printed to the console and the program should not continue any further.

The version with normal error-first callbacks works just fine, but I ran into an issue with the split-callback version. It only copies file2.txt, but not file1.txt.

Here is the code I use for transforming the fs-functions:

```
const fs = require('fs');

fs.exists = function(path, callback) {
    fs.stat(path, (err, stats) => {
        if (err) {
            callback(null, false);
        } else {
            callback(null, true);
        }
    });
};

function splitCallback(f) {
    return (...params) => {
        reject  = params[params.length - 2];
        resolve = params[params.length - 1];
        params  = params.slice(0, params.length - 2);
        f(...params, (err, data) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(data);
            }
        });
    };
}

const sfs = {};
const functionNames = ['exists', 'readdir', 'unlink', 'mkdir', 'readFile', 'writeFile'];
for (const functionName of functionNames) {
    sfs[functionName] = splitCallback(fs[functionName].bind(fs));
}
```

And this is the actual example using those functions:

```
function handleError(err) {
    console.error(err);
}

function initCopyDirectory(callback) {
    sfs.exists('copy', handleError, exists => {
        if (exists) {
            sfs.readdir('copy', handleError, filenames => {
                let fileCount = filenames.length;
                if (fileCount === 0) {
                    callback();
                }
                for (const filename of filenames) {
                    sfs.unlink(`copy/${filename}`, handleError, () => {
                        fileCount--;
                        if (fileCount === 0) {
                            callback();
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        } else {
            sfs.mkdir('copy', handleError, () => callback);
        }
    });
}

function copyFiles() {
    // sfs.readdir('orig', handleError, filenames => {
    //     for (const filename of filenames) {
    //         console.log(filename);
    //         sfs.readFile(`orig/${filename}`, handleError, data => {
    //             console.log('reading', filename);
    //             sfs.writeFile(`copy/${filename}`, data, handleError, () => {
    //                 console.log('writing', filename);
    //             });
    //         });
    //     }
    // });
    sfs.readdir('orig', handleError, filenames => {
        for (const filename of filenames) {
            fs.readFile(`orig/${filename}`, (err, data) => {
                if (err) {
                    handleError(err);
                } else {
                    sfs.writeFile(`copy/${filename}`, data, handleError, () => {});
                }
            });
        }
    });
}

function main() {
    initCopyDirectory(copyFiles);
}

main();
```

As it is written here it works properly (using Node version 7.4.0 for Windows), but when I swap the comments in the copyFiles-function (thereby changing readFile) only one file is copied and I get the following output:

```
file1.txt
file2.txt
reading file2.txt
writing file2.txt
writing file2.txt
```

What is the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Try this instead of the commented code:

```
     for (const filename of filenames) {
         (function(filename){
             console.log(filename);
             sfs.readFile(`orig/${filename}`, handleError, data => {
                 console.log('reading', filename);
                 sfs.writeFile(`copy/${filename}`, data, handleError, () => {
                     console.log('writing', filename);
                 });
             });
         })(filename)
     }
```

The problem is that you are running asynchronous functions inside a for loop and expecting them to behave synchronously. By the time `sfs.writeFile` is called (after executing `sfs.readFile`) the for loop has long been finished executing and so you are left with only the last filename, file2. By wrapping everything inside the for loop in a closure you maintain the proper values.

Here is a simpler example:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
   setTimeout(function(){
       console.log(i)
   }, 100)
}
```

will print `10` 10 times because by the time the timeout executes (0.1 seconds) the for loop is already done, whereas the following code will print the numbers 0 through 9 because the original values are preserved by the closure. (try it yourself)

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10 ; i++) {
   (function(i){
       setTimeout(function(){
           console.log(i)
       }, 100)
   })(i)
}
```

Comment: That is what I thought at first, too, but I get the same result here. And according to [this](http://exploringjs.com/es6/ch_for-of.html#_iteration-variables-const-declarations-versus-var-declarations) I should get a fresh binding for const-declared variables in a for-of loop in each iteration.

Comment: @Ignavia what do you mean by "a fresh binding". Using const will not change the fact that you cannot preserve the binding in asynchronous functions inside for loop which will always be faster than any async function

Comment: Using your simple example in a slightly changed form: `const a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
for (var i of a) {
   setTimeout(function(){
       console.log(i);
   }, 100);
}` produces ten times 10 as output, while `const a = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];
for (const i of a) {
   setTimeout(function(){
       console.log(i);
   }, 100);
}` produces the numbers from 1 to 10. There is a better formatted version under the link in the first comment.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was that I forgot to put const in front of the variable declarations in splitCallback. This made them global variables that kept being overridden. Activating strict mode would have thrown an error instead. Here is the correct code:

```
function splitCallback(f) {
    return (...params) => {
        const input             = params.slice(0, params.length - 2);
        const [reject, resolve] = params.slice(params.length - 2);
        f(...input, (err, ...output) => {
            if (err) {
                reject(err);
            } else {
                resolve(...output);
            }
        });
    };
}
```